# ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Problem with deploying Django app to Heroku [Windows]

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Django app to Heroku but I keep having this error after successfully building the app.
Build log:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-geo-buildpack.git
-----> Geo Packages (GDAL/GEOS/PROJ) app detected
-----> Installing GDAL-2.4.0
-----> Installing GEOS-3.7.2
-----> Installing PROJ-5.2.0
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 50.9M
-----> Launching...
       Released v5
       https://metamedapp.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

This is the log after a successful build:

```
2021-03-16T15:21:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-03-16T15:21:32.647557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-16T15:21:36.820238+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:49625`
2021-03-16T15:21:39.146005+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-16T15:21:39.146029+00:00 app[web.1]: File "manage.py", line 11, in main
2021-03-16T15:21:39.146029+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
2021-03-16T15:21:39.146030+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2021-03-16T15:21:39.146030+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-16T15:21:39.146031+00:00 app[web.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2021-03-16T15:21:39.146031+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-16T15:21:39.146031+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-16T15:21:39.146032+00:00 app[web.1]: File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
2021-03-16T15:21:39.146032+00:00 app[web.1]: main()
2021-03-16T15:21:39.146032+00:00 app[web.1]: File "manage.py", line 13, in main
2021-03-16T15:21:39.146033+00:00 app[web.1]: raise ImportError(
2021-03-16T15:21:39.146046+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
2021-03-16T15:21:39.193415+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-03-16T15:21:39.280185+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-16T15:22:38.622544+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=metamedapp.herokuapp.com request_id=1fccc50d-d117-4cab-862c-91d05b765c4d fwd="86.7.108.29" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-16T15:22:39.701300+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=metamedapp.herokuapp.com request_id=723d001f-0cf6-4291-b884-e5d7772d9d3c fwd="86.7.108.29" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I definitely have Django installed:
[django version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVHRV.png)

I haven't used virtualenv during development of my application. Also I'm not sure if this matters but I'm not using a python buildpack since it kept raising errors saying my gdal.dlls couldn't be found.

This is my requirements.txt file which has django as one of the dependencies:

```
asgiref==3.3.1
attrs==20.3.0
branca==0.4.2
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
click==7.1.2
click-plugins==1.1.1
cligj==0.7.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-static==0.0.6
django==3.1.5
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
folium==0.12.1
geographiclib==1.50
geojson==2.5.0
geopandas==0.9.0
geopy==2.1.0
googlemaps==4.4.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.10
Jinja2==2.11.3
leaflet==0.0.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
munch==2.5.0
numpy==1.20.1
pandas==1.2.2
prettyprint==0.1.5
psycopg2==2.8.6
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
pyproj==3.0.0.post1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.5
requests==2.25.1
Shapely==1.7.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
static3==0.7.0
urllib3==1.26.3
waitress==2.0.0
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

And here's my Procfile:

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

The app works fine locally but it's only when I push it to heroku that it starts giving me this error. I've been at this for hours and just can't seem to fix it.

Comment: Try doing `python3` in procfile. `python` still usually means Python2.7 in linux environments because some stuff still requires 2.7 and uses plain `python` shebang

Comment: @h4z3 I probably should've mentioned I'm using Windows, I added it to the title now. But I tried changing `python` to `python3` in the procfile and the issue still persisted.

Comment: Could you show your deploy log?

Comment: @h4z3 I'm assuming that's the same as the build log, I've added it to the post

Comment: Okay, so simple thing: where is your `requirements.txt` located when you upload it to heroku? I haven't played with heroku but the log doesn't say anything about installing your packages, so I assume it just cannot find them (not only django).